# Does Django DRF have a way to do read-only tokens?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST API using Django REST Framework.
I want to use [TokenAuthentication](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f56b85b7dd7e4f786e0769bba6b7609d4507da83/rest_framework/authentication.py#L151), but I want to have read-only tokens and read-write tokens. Read-only just has access to GET methods. Read-Write have access to everything (POST, PUT, DELETE, etc).

Does DRF already have something for this? Or would I just create my own [Token](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f56b85b7dd7e4f786e0769bba6b7609d4507da83/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py#L9) model with an extra field that keeps track of the type of token, and use my own version of `TokenAuthentication` that returns a 403 if the token is READ_ONLY, and the method is other than a GET method?

I don't want to be re-inventing the wheel here if this already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using token auth for auth only. Permissions should be used to manage the level of access. After a user is authenticated you should be able to just use the permission system to route users accordingly

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

if you look specifically at the `DjangoObjectPermissions` documentation you can seen reference for how to restrict different methods based on the permissions granted to the user.